# In GCM registration my app is crashing

Tags: android

My menifest permission is below code

```
<permission
        android:name="com.xyz.xyz.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission 

android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
```

this is the crash

Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1794)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1771)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:521)
       at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzc(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: Have you tried other posts which is related to same issue on SO?

Comment: yes i have tried, in that they are telling to add this line <uses-permission 

android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

Comment: or is it because of the playservice is not available in the device or disabled......also this crash i am not getting frequently, after so long i got this issue

Comment: Yes if play service is not available on device or disabled then google service will not work

Comment: ohk thanks for confirmation, may be on user device playservice is disabled or...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed official [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) ?
Apart from your receiver (which is not clear from your quoted part of manifest) you'd need to grant permissions to SDK's receiver, i.e.

```
   <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="<your-package-name>" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Required to wakeup the device and deliver messages -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission android:name="your_package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="your_package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```